# C# list keeps losing content

Tags: c#, list, constructor

I'm a beginner programmer trying examples of factories (and many other things) and my generic list keeps wiping out the data and I have no idea how - what am I doing wrong (probably a multitude)?

Outline:

1. program creates a new CreditCards object (just a use case).
2. CreditCards creates a CC factory object
3. program calls CreditCards.Apply which then calls the CC factory to create the "right" CC for the user based on their credit
4. program calls CreditCards.Holder which lists all the credit cards produces at the factory

I was defining List collectionofCreditCards in CCFactory class and newing it up in the constructor with collectionofCreditCards = new List() - but it kept blowing up with null (??).  Gave up and put         public List collectionofCreditCards = new List() in the class, but now every time CreditCards.Apply exists, the list goes back to 0.  So confused...

Thanks for any tips/tricks/advice/pointers!

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreditCards mycreditcard = new CreditCards(); // as part of constructor, it creats a "credit card factory"

            mycreditcard.Apply();
            mycreditcard.Apply();
            mycreditcard.Holder();
        }
    }


public class CreditCards
    {
        int product;
        CC unknownCC;
        CCFactory myCCfactory;

        public CreditCards()
        {
            myCCfactory = new CCFactory("Primary Facility");
            Console.WriteLine($"Your credit card will be produced at the:{myCCfactory.FactoryName}");
        }

        public void Apply()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is your credit score great, good, or bad?");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (input)
            {
                case "great":
                    product = 1;
                    break;
                case "good":
                    product = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    product = 3;
                    break;
            }
            unknownCC = myCCfactory.CreateProduct(product);
            Console.WriteLine(unknownCC); // display credit card details of the manufactured credit card
        }

        public void Holder()
        {
            myCCfactory.ListProducts(); // list all the credit cards produced at the factory
        }
    }
}

public class CCFactory
    {
        PlatinumFactory newPF;
        TitaniumFactory newTF;
        MoneyBackFactory newMBF;
        private string factoryName;
        public List<CC> collectionofCreditCards = new List<CC>();

        public string FactoryName
        {
            get { return factoryName; }
            set { factoryName = value; }
        }

        public CCFactory(string factory)
        {
            factoryName = factory;
            newPF = new PlatinumFactory();
            newTF = new TitaniumFactory();
            newMBF = new MoneyBackFactory();
        }

        public void AddProduct(CC newCC)
        {
            collectionofCreditCards.Add(newCC);
        }

        public void ListProducts()
        {
            foreach (var item in collectionofCreditCards)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Credit card: {item}");
            }
        }

        public CC CreateProduct(int product)
        {
            switch (product)
            {
                case 1:
                    return newPF.MakeProduct();
                case 2:
                    return newTF.MakeProduct();
                case 3:
                    return newMBF.MakeProduct();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        protected virtual CC MakeProduct()
        {
            return this.MakeProduct();
        }
 
    }

    class PlatinumFactory : CCFactory
    {
        protected override CC MakeProduct()
        {
            CC product = new Platinum();
            AddProduct(product);
            return product;
        }

    }
    class TitaniumFactory : CCFactory.....
    class MoneyBackFactory : CCFactory.....


public abstract class CC
    {
        protected string Name;
        protected string CCNumber;
        protected string expirationdate;
        protected string ccv;
    }

    public class Titanium : CC
    {
        public Titanium()
        {
            Name = "Titanium";
            CCNumber = "1-TIT";
            expirationdate = "01/21";
            ccv = "222";
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Name:" + Name + " CCNumber:" + CCNumber + " Expiration Date:" + expirationdate + "CCV:" + ccv; 
        }
    }
    public class Platinum : CC...
    public class MoneyBack : CC...
}
```

Comment: So, have you debugged this with a step debugger? When you did, and you inspected the variables at each stage, what was your conclusion?

Comment: `CCFactory.CreateProduct` doesn't add to it's own list. TBH this whole code is a bit of a code smell. Why is `PlatinumFactory` etc a derived class of `CCFactory` but then `CCFactory` has it's own Factories inside it as fields?

Comment: You're not adding the credit card to the main factory, you're adding to the specific factories collection. Why have 3 different factories nested? In addition, CCFactory.MakeProduct will end in a stackoverflowexception. CCFactory should be abstract and MakeProduct abstract too in parent class.

Comment: @00110001 - Yes - the collection inits after the call to newPF.MakeProduct. ??

Comment: @Charlieface - thanks for the help.  Yes, it stinks for sure; it's an experiment. I've renamed my username to n00b accordingly.  ```CCFactory.CreateProduct``` adds to the list by means of ```CreateProduct->MakeProduct->AddProduct```.  As to why I'm deriving the factories, it's to call the appropriate factory when referencing a product (e.g. factory line 1 handles Platinum cards).  ```CCFactory``` is the "metafactory" that controls all the others.  ```collectionofCreditCards``` resets count after the return from MakeProduct.  Not sure why.

Comment: It doesn't "reset", it's referring at one point to the derived list and at another point to the non-derived list. These are different objects. Check the value of `this` in the "Locals" window as you step through. @DrkDeveloper is right, the whole base class should be abstract, you should not be "new"ing it directly

Comment: @DrkDeveloper - appreciate the insight and time. What do you mean by it's not adding to the main factory? I see the ```collectionofCreditCards``` incremented the list by 1 but then back to 0 after call to MakeProduct (why is that?).  I didn't put CCFactory as abstract so it could be a command and control for all the other factories.  Def re: stackoverflow on MakeProduct, but don't know why. Thx again!

Comment: The list is not static, it belongs to the instance of any particular factory. You are creating both a base and derived instances. **If you follow `this` parameter in the Locals windows you will see this happen**

Comment: @Charlieface - thanks! Redid but still stuck - feedback much appreciated: I define an abstract CC base (```CC requestedCC```) -> determine user's credit and create derived object (```requestedCC = new Platinum();```) -> call static class/method (```MetaFactory.AddProduct(requestedCC);```) which adds the CC to a static list in MetaFactory; but I want to call the derived factory (e.g. PF) by calling the base factory (CCF) with requestedCC as a parameter and have it sort out which to go to by override/polymorphism.  (e.g. ```CCFactory.MakeProduct(requestedCC)```) Possible? thx again

Comment: I think then you would need a generic `ICreditCardFactory<TCreditCard>` interface, and a static generic function to loop through your static list and find the right factory, something like `factoryList.OfType<ICreditCardFactory<TCreditCard>>().FirstOrDefault()`. This is basically Dependency Injection

Comment: @Charlieface - ooof!  Just the name dependency injection strikes fear.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Charlieface and @DrkDeveloper.  Revised code after considering reflection, polymorphism, dynamic, static.... :-) HTH others / feedback welcome.
`
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
CreditCards.Apply(); …
CreditCards.ListProducts();
}
}

```
public static class CreditCards
{
    static CC requestedCC; 

    public static void Apply()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("is your credit score great, good, or bad?");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (input)
        {
            case "great":
                requestedCC = new Platinum();
                break;
            default:
                requestedCC = new MoneyBack();
                break;
        }
        FactoryController.ManufactureProduct(requestedCC);
    }

    public static void ListProducts()
    {
        FactoryController.ListProducts();
    }
}

public static class FactoryController
{
    static PlatinumFactory newPF = new PlatinumFactory();
    …
    static public List<CC> collectionofCreditCards = new List<CC>();
    static CCFactory GenericFactory;

    public static void ManufactureProduct(CC newCC)
    {
        switch (newCC)
        {
            case Platinum:
                GenericFactory = newPF;
                Console.WriteLine("Platinum");
                break;
            case Titanium:
                GenericFactory = newTF;
                Console.WriteLine("Titanium");
                break;
        default:
                GenericFactory = newMBF;
                Console.WriteLine("Money Back");
                break;
        }
        GenericFactory.ManufactureProduct(newCC);
        collectionofCreditCards.Add(newCC);
    }

    public static void ListProducts()
    {
        foreach (var item in collectionofCreditCards)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Credit card: {item}");
        }
    }

}
public class CCFactory
{
    public virtual void ManufactureProduct(CC passedCC)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class PlatinumFactory : CCFactory
{
    List<CC> collectionofPlatinumCards = new List<CC>();
    public override void ManufactureProduct(CC product)
    {
        collectionofPlatinumCards.Add(product);
    }
}
```

`